# How to show columns from different tables without using JOIN?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

```
SELECT date,v2ProductName,sum(productRevenue) as Revenue ,v2ProductCategory,promoName,concat(trafficSource.source,'/', trafficSource.medium) as source_medium
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170*`
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hits) as h
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(product) as p
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(promotion) as promo
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '601' AND '701'
and
productRevenue is not Null
Group by date, v2ProductName,v2ProductCategory ,promoname, source_medium
ORDER BY date ASC
```

When I UNNEST tables like shown above the promotion table shows all values as null, I think that is due to wrong usage of left join.

I'm not sure how else can I join it. And is there any way I can do it differently without using join??

I kept using left joins as I'm used to it working but this time I feel it's wrong.

Comment: Can you share a sample of what you got, and a sample of what you expect?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Well I cannot at the moment because I'm out of quota. But I expect the promoName column to return some values where it actually return nulls only.

Comment: looks there is no case where `product` and `promotion`  has values at the same time in a row.